# How to convert a space into non breaking space entity in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert  more that `spaces` in a string to `&nbsp;` through c#?

Like if string is

```
       My name  is this.
```

then output should be

```
   My name &nbsp;is this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction  the line below will not work

Please use Server.HtmlEncode for it

You will have to do it by code

```
string s = " ";
if(s == " ")
{
 s = "&nbsp;"
}

Or use "My name  is this".Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Comment: It'll encode the text but it won't convert to non breaking spaces.

Comment: @TomRider It'll replace **every** space with a nbsp, not only the one after the first one, anyway it may be OK in you case!

Comment: Please may I request to explain -1

Comment: This answer is poorly formatted, poorly explained, and seems to be three answers combined into one.

Answer (score 28):

Replace the "regular" space with the "non-breaking space" Unicode character:

```
string outputString = "Input text".Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with RegEx if you need to convert **multiple spaces** to a **single non-breaking-space**:

```
string convertedText =
    new Regex("[ ]{2,}").Replace(textToConvert, "&nbsp;");
```

Example:

```
My Name   is this
  ^    ^^^  ^
```

It'll be changed to:

```
My Name &nbsp;is this
```

**UPDATE**
If you need to preserve extra spaces (and to replace with nbsp only multiple spaces) you may use [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372825/java-regex-that-only-replaces-multiple-whitepaces-with-non-breaking-spaces):

```
string convertedText =
    new Regex(" (?= )|(?<= ) ").Replace(textToConvert, "&nbsp;");
```

Example:

```
My Name   is this
  ^    ^^^  ^
```

It'll be changed to:

```
My Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;is this
```

For the second case, as alternative, you may even do not use regex at all (just loop) but they should be faster if you have to do it often with the same regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string myString = "My name  is this".Replace("  ", " &nbsp;");
```

Comment: what if OP has 3, 4, 5... spaces?

Comment: @oleksii This replaces every pair of spaces with a space followed by `&nbsp;`. You end up with: " &nbsp; ", " &nbsp; &nbsp;", and " &nbsp; &nbsp; "