# String replace continuous whitespace only

Tags: java, regex

I have String like:

```
test    text test
```

I want to keep single space as it is and replace multiple spaces with `&nbsp;` 
So it will become:

```
tets&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text test
```

Can anyone here please suggest me `regex`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372825/java-regex-that-only-replaces-multiple-whitepaces-with-non-breaking-spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following replacement:

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("((?<= ) | (?= ))", "&nbsp;");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/kNb7rd

**Explanation:** I am using lookahead and lookbehind features of Regex here. `((?<= ) | (?= ))` means find a space which is either **preceded by a space `(?<= )`** OR **followed by a space `(?= )`** This will make sure single space is not replaced but all multiple spaces are replaced. See this link for more details on lookarounds: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @rot: Explanation added with the answer.

Comment: @rot: You're welcome. If this answer worked for you then pls mark it accepted by clicking the green tick mark :P

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will help you..

It replace `Multiple spaces` with `Single Space`..

```
YourString.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Comment: It might be more effective to use `"  +"` with two spaces as first argument, since it won't replace a single space with another single space.

Comment: @Keppil : Yes but he want to replace only multiple spaces right..?

Comment: Yes, but your regex also replaces one space with one space, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "test    text test ";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="test     text test";
str=str.replaceAll("\\s\\s","&nbsp;&nbsp;");
str=str.replaceAll("&nbsp;\\s","&nbsp;&nbsp;");//It will work for Odd number
```

The first replace will leave a blank space if there are odd number of spaces so the second can solve that problem.